# Get formatted data in shell script which is read from file containing JSON data

Tags: json, shell, jq

Writting one shell script to automatically get list of name, current and latest available version from raw json data.

I am trying to format JSON data stored in file using shell script. I tried using [JQ](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line JSON parser.

I want to get formatted JSON data in script. Their is advanced option provided in JQ for same scenario. I am not able to use it properly.

Example: File containing Following JSON

```
{
  "endpoint": {
    "name": "test-plugin",
    "version": "0.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "plugin1": {
      "main": {
        "name": "plugin1name",
        "description": "Dummy text"
      },
      "pkgMeta": {
        "name": "plugin1name",
        "version": "0.0.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {},
      "versions": [
        "0.0.5",
        "0.0.4",
        "0.0.3",
        "0.0.2",
        "0.0.1"
      ],
      "update": {
        "latest": "0.0.5"
      }
    },
    "plugin2": {
      "main": {
        "name": "plugin2name",
        "description": "Dummy text"
      },
      "pkgMeta": {
        "name": "plugin2name",
        "version": "0.1.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {},
      "versions": [
        "0.1.5",
        "0.1.4",
        "0.1.3",
        "0.1.2",
        "0.1.1"
      ],
      "update": {
        "latest": "0.1.5"
      }
    }

   }
}
```

Trying to get result in format

```
[{name: "plugin1name", 
    c_version: "0.0.1", 
    n_version: "0.0.5"
 },
 {name: "plugin2name", 
    c_version: "0.1.1", 
    n_version: "0.1.5"}]
```

Can someone suggest anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json file is not valid at: `.dependencies.pkgMeta.version`.

After fixing your json file, try this command:

```
jq '
  .dependencies |
    to_entries |
      map(.value |
        {
          name: .main.name,
          c_version: .pkgMeta.version,
          n_version: .update.latest
        }
      )' input.json
```

---

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "plugin1name",
    "c_version": "0.0.1",
    "n_version": "0.0.5"
  },
  {
    "name": "plugin2name",
    "c_version": "0.1.1",
    "n_version": "0.1.5"
  }
]
```